# parsing time command in perl

Tags: regex, perl, solaris

When i issue the command /usr/bin/time script.sh it can vary in time because of the load of course (sometimes could be 10 secs and sometime could be 2 minutes), problem is that i need notification if time execution is higher than 30 sec (could also include minutes..) and warning if is 20-30 seconds.
What is the best way to catch all time values for requested tresholds:

```
/usr/bin/time ./script.sh | awk'/real/ {print $2}' 
30.0
/usr/bin/time ./script.sh | awk'/real/ {print $2}'
1:24.2
/usr/bin/time ./script.sh | awk'/real/ {print $2}' 
3.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following warning thresholds:

- **Critical:** 30 seconds or longer
- **Warning:** 20 seconds to 30 seconds
- **OK:** less than 20 seconds

And based on the output of /usr/bin/time on your machine, which seems to use a format of `hh:mm:ss.d` with optional hours and minutes places:

```
my $time = `/usr/bin/time ./vladtest.sh | awk '/real/ {print $2}'`
my $status;
if ($time =~ /^[01]?\d\./) {       # time is 0-9 seconds or 10-19 seconds
    $status = "OK";
}
elsif ($time =~ /^(2\d|30)\./) {   # time is 20-30 seconds
    $status = "WARNING";
}
else {                             # any other time is critical
    $status = "CRITICAL";
}
```

Comment: thanks qwrrty this regexp works just fine,

Comment: also can i add after if, elsif and else another line to print for example (CRITICAL execution of command is 50.12 seconds) ?

Comment: Sure, don't see why not.

Comment: hm i still have problems with this seems like this regexp do not parse anything exept critical ..