# Matching strings in perl

Tags: regex, perl

```
if ($time =~ /^[01]?\d\./) {       # time is 0-9 seconds or 10-19 seconds
    $status = "OK";
}
elsif ($time =~ /^(2\d|30)\./) {   # time is 20-30 seconds
    $status = "WARNING";
}
else {                             # any other time is critical
    $status = "CRITICAL";
}
```

In the above code I have some thresholds. 
What I need is to change 0–10 to `OK`, 10–30 to `WARNING` and everything else is `CRITICAL`.
The string is a time like `1.0`, `1.11`, `13.51`, or `2:13.52`.

Comment: Is `10` `OK` or `WARNING`?

Comment: Can time be negative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's often said that when you have a hammer, every problem begins to look like a nail, and this is true in this case, where you're using pattern matching to do a simple numerical comparison.

Why aren't you evaluating these as numbers? It'd be far more maintainable.

```
$status = "CRITICAL";
if ($time =~ /^(\d+)\./) { # Starts with seconds
    $seconds = $1;
    $status = "WARNING" if ($seconds <= 30);
    $status = "OK" if ($seconds <= 10);
    # If status is OK, print a message
    print "$status: Execution took $seconds seconds" if ($status eq "OK");
} else {
    # Time doesn't start with seconds, so status is critical
}
```

Now, in future, anyone who wants to change the thresholds can just modify the numbers in the simple numerical comparators.

Comment: For reference, please see the poster's earlier question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20620461/parsing-time-command-in-perl  The `$time` variable may include minutes or hours, e.g. `5:44.3`.

Comment: @qwrrty If that's true, the examples in his OP don't work as he's searching for seconds at the start of the string.

Comment: they only include minutes if it is at least 1 minute, presumably

Comment: Sure they will: if `$time` is e.g. `15.4` then it will match the WARNING clause. Any time that is one minute or more is inherently CRITICAL anyway.

Comment: @qwrrty Have edited, since any time starting with minutes is a `CRITICAL` status this will work as it will fail to match.

Comment: Ok, and how can i incorporate that with print if execution is for example 12 seconds

Comment: @vladeli What do you want to print, and when?

Comment: when execution is 0-10 seconds print OK and print how many seconds, for warning and critical also

Answer (score 2):

You are using regexes for something they aren't suited for. It would be better to

1. Extract the number from the string
2. Use numerical comparision operators to assign a level

This might look like:

```
sub level {
  my ($time) = @_;
  $time =~ /\A (?: (?: (?<hours>[0-9]+): )? (?<minutes>[0-9]+): )?  (?<seconds>[0-9]+) [.]/x
    or die "Can't match seconds";
  my $seconds = $+{seconds} + 60 * ($+{minutes} + 60*$+{hours});

  my $warning  = 20;
  my $critical = 31;

  my $status = ($seconds < $warning ) ? "OK"
             : ($seconds < $critical) ? "WARNING"
             :                          "CRITICAL";
  return $status;
}

use Test::More tests => 8;

is level("1.0"),     "OK";
is level("1.11"),    "OK";
is level("13.51"),   "OK";
is level("2:13.52"), "CRITICAL";
is level("26.0"),    "WARNING";
is level("26.11"),   "WARNING";
is level("2:26.52"), "CRITICAL";
is level("0:26.52"), "WARNING";
```

Comment: note that one of the examples provided is "2:13.52", on which you will die

Comment: if there are minutes, it should be critical

Comment: 2:13.52 should be `CRITICAL`.